# Running multiple threads in a Service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I'm trying to run threads simultaneously. I followed the services guide on the Android developers site (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

I modified the code slightly so that instead of just waiting 5 seconds, every second a message is logged.

The output is:
msg1
msg1
msg1
msg1
msg1

The problem is that I can't figure out how to run two of these threads at the same time, such that the output is:
msg1 msg2 msg1 msg2....

I keep getting msg1 msg1 msg1 msg1 msg1 msg2 msg2 msg2...

Here is the code from my onStartCommand():

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
    Log.v("testService","onStartCommand()");

    new Thread() {
        // This method is called when the thread runs
        public void run() {
            Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage();
            msg.arg1 = startId;
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Shouldn't this create a new thread for each request so that the previous request isn't block?

Answer (score 0):

It will create a new Thread to **send** each request to the Handler, but the code for the Handler will execute on whatever Thread instantiated the Handler, not the Thread that sends the message. The whole point of Handlers is to provide a simple method for inter-thread communication.